# Deep sleep keyboard shortcut

Tags: macos, keyboard, sleep-wake, mac-mini

I have been a windows user for a long time now and I have been used to pressing just one key in my keyboard to hibernate the machine every night. I recently bought a mac mini and I press <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>Eject</kbd> to put it to sleep and then it would go to deep sleep in a while. But I am wondering if there is a keyboard shortcut to do this or maybe change the default sleep to a deep sleep.

Mac mini late 2012 with standard HDD, i5, 4gb ram

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two keyboard shortcuts for sleep:
Display sleep: <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>Eject</kbd>
Computer sleep: <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>Option</kbd>+<kbd>Eject</kbd>

Source: http://support.apple.com/kb/ht1343

To change the default sleep mode to hibernate (in the terminal):

```
sudo pmset -a hibernatemode 25
```

I don't think there's any way to preserve the normal sleep behaviour and have a separate keyboard shortcut for hibernation without writing a script that changes to hibernate mode when called and changes it back after, somehow, but this command does work on my MBP. There's a number of options for sleep that you can see with:

```
man pmset
```

Comment: Yes my bad, I meant to say Option + Command + Eject. But its not the deep sleep.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understand what you meant by deep sleep. I've amended my answer with how to change the default sleep mode.

Comment: Thats exactly what I needed. Usually when you put the mac to sleep the light blinks. After like 4 hours it goes into Deep sleep (hibernate) where the light doesnt blink

Comment: **On laptops—not by default on desktops:** Even if you _don't_ hibernate it, a loss of power will result in it restoring as if it were hibernating—when the system goes to sleep, it saves a "sleep image" to disk (by default, it can be changed). See the "safe sleep arguments" section of `man pmset` for details.